# Protect a GET and POST endpoint?

Tags: python, django, api

I'm trying to protect a GET and a POST endpoint on my backend. The user is not logged in, but I want to prevent ppl from accessing the API endpoint unless they're using my app.

I'm using React and axios to make the request, with Django and Python accepting the request. I'm trying to use a CSRF decorator:

```
class ClassView(View):

   @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
   def get(self, request):
      # Protected endpoint.

   @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
   def post(self, request):
      # Protected endpoint.
```

This doesn't work because I can still go directly to the API endpoint and make requests. I've also tried `@requires_csrf_token` and `@csrf_protect` without success.

Comment: How do you call the API endpoints? In the browser? You realize that CSRF is put in the header of the request?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem: I'm using Axios to call the API requests. --- I don't understand what you mean about CSRF is put in the header of the request.

Answer (score 1):

Are these login endpoints? If so, you need them to be accessible publicly AFAIK. If you want to limit it to your app, then I suppose add some sort of header or access token in your axios request to the endpoint, this way only requests from your app would have permission to use the endpoint. Have a function as middleware on the server checking for that specific access token or whatever.

Comment: ---The GET endpoint sends a request to an external API which charges if I go over the monthly limit. (This is the one I specifically want to protect.) ---The POST request performs calculations on data the user submits. (This one isn't as important to protect.) ---How do I add a header or access token to the Axios request? ---A function as middleware on the server... isn't that what the @ decorator is supposed to do?